# Initializer List Perfomance in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am totally new to programming in c++  and now learning about constructors. In a blog post about constructors which I read before written that using "Initializer list" is better that assigning values inside body in the class constructor when initialzing class variables due to performance reasons. But there are not any explanation reasons behind it. If you can explain it I would be grateful.

Comment: The difference is the compiler can figure that (initializer list)  out at compile time, while writing code in the body will be needed to be executed at runtime.

Comment: The question makes no sense. What a braced-init-list does depends significantly on the type you're trying to initialize. Therefore, talking about the performance of such code can only be done with regard to a specific case, not generally.

Comment: Item 4 of effective C++

Comment: objects except built int types are default constructed before the body constuctor executes, so when you assigned value inside the body constuctor its just overwriting the constructed objects (construction then assignment), but initializer list avoids this one (initializer list only use copy constructor unless u used default constructor)

Comment: The simplest (over-simplified, really) example I can think of is that generally speaking, any member that isn't specifically initialised in the member initializer list will be default-initialised anyways, so you're assigning to it twice instead of once.  It's not _actually_ as simple as that (some members are required to be initialised in the initializer list, and some members won't be default-initialised if not explicitly initialised), but that gives a rough idea of one of the benefits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly your question in not complete. There are some specific cases indeed. But for simplicity :

```
class Foo {
    ExampleType var;
public:
    Foo(ExampleType x):var(x) {

    }
};
```

Firstly the copy constructor of “ExampleType” class is called to initialize : var(x) then destructor of “ExampleType” is called for “x” since it goes out.
But in variable assignment case, firstly constructor called for Example type then assignment operator is called and so the destructor called.